# Learning to Rank: query-dependent vs. query-independent features

Tags: machine-learning, ranking, information-retrieval, supervised-learning

I've been doing some reading about learning to rank - specifically lambdaMART - and one thing I am confused about is the role of features. When training a model, should one only use query-dependent features (as in features derived from both the query and document)? 
Could you train on a set of query-independent features (things like document length)? Both? 
Is there any references which address this?

I hope this makes sense.